# What fomrat is the smallest in size for black white pictures (no gray)?

Tags: graphics, compression, format, image

I am looking for a format a method (tool?) which could be used for picture compression, so that the size for black and white (no grey) picture is as small as possible.

Comment: Do you mean like the fax formats? If so [this link](http://www.fileformat.info/mirror/egff/ch09_05.htm) might be useful.

Answer (score 0):

The smallest raw, uncompressed encoding for a monochrome image is to use 1 8-bit byte to pack 8 pixels. However, compression is also possible. As Roger Rowland indicated, CCITT encoding is a possibility. Another one I know if is the Apple Animation (RLE) codec which can be stored in QuickTime files. That can be decoded by QuickTime Player as well as VLC. One trade-off you need to consider is what program will consume the data you're producing. Will it be a program you're writing? Uploaded to YouTube?